# Using Bootstrap Modal in Single Page AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a single page app in AungarJS made using `ui.router` and I want to integrate Bootstrap Modals in my app from this link:

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/getting_started

But so far my integration has failed severely. That's because the link says that in case of UI Routers I need to `$uibResolve.setResolver('$resolve')` in configuration. But using `$uibResolve` gives injection error.

My question: how can I integrate Bootsrap Modals in aforementioned link in my single page app?

Comment: Are you using a pre-1.0 ui-router version? "If one wants to have the modal resolve using UI Router's **pre-1.0** resolve mechanism, one can call $uibResolve.setResolver('$resolve') in the configuration phase of the application"

Comment: apparently not. How do I make this work for higher version?

Comment: I don't know, but if I had to guess, you just wouldn't need to do that step. Probably works out of the box

Comment: that's the thing.. im not doing that step and its still not working

Answer (score 1):

You should inject `$uibResolveProvider` and call `$uibResolveProvider.setResolver('$resolve')`

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

> ** the service object is not available during the config phase, but the provider instance is (see the unicornLauncherProvider example above).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: [Configure this using the `onEnter` property of the `state` config to open a modal when you transition to that state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-open-a-dialogmodal-at-a-certain-state).

It's not clear from your question which versions of angular, ui-bootstrap, and ui-router you are using, but I have created a snippet to demonstrate. It should be adaptable to your situation, unless you are using much older versions of each.

```js
var app = angular.module('uiRouterModal', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
  $stateProvider
  .state('index', {
    url: '/',
    template: '<h2>Base state</h2>'
  })
  .state('modal', {
    url: '/modal',
    onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$uibModal', function($stateParams, $state, $uibModal) {
      $uibModal.open({
        template: [
        '<div class="modal-content">',
          '<div class="modal-header">',
            '<h3 class="modal-title">Modal state</h3>',
          '</div>',
          '<div class="modal-body">',
          'I did it!',
          '</div>',
          '<div class="modal-footer">',
            '<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="dismiss()">OK</button>',
          '</div>',
        '</div>'
        ].join(''),
        resolve: {}, // can resolve any data and pass to controller 
        controller: function($uibModalInstance, $scope){
          $scope.dismiss = function() {
            $uibModalInstance.dismiss();
          };
        }
      });
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="uiRouterModal">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>UI-Router and UI-Bootstrap Modal</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@0.3.1" data-semver="0.3.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.1.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
    <a ui-sref="modal">Click for modal</a>
  </body>

</html>
```